# Is there a way to position something based on the centre of the screen (horizontally) with CSS?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do this:

1. Position something centre-screen horizontally (easy).
2. Offset it's position from the centre.

I normally achieve this by making a `<div>` with a width double of the amount I want to offset by, set it to `margin: auto;` and then put my desired element within this floated either left or right. This works fine, I just thought there might be a shorter way.

An an example, I might want to have a `<div>` positioned 80px to the left of the centre of the screen, like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html) is what you're seeking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
body { position: relative }

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;

  /* Origins from the screen center */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  margin-top: -125px; /* height / 2 */
  margin-left: -230px; /* (width / 2) - 80 */
  /* The margin left would be -150px but you want it to move 80 pixels to left */
}
```

Here's an online example: http://jsfiddle.net/B4rDJ/2/ (thanks Purmou!)

Comment: Here's an example of this that I whipped up, with dotted lines marking the centers as well (and without vertical centering): http://jsfiddle.net/B4rDJ/

Comment: How silly of me--the positioning on the above link is inaccurate. Anyways, here's a modified and proper version, also with a div 80px wide to show that it actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/B4rDJ/1/

Comment: Thanks guys, never considered the use of `left: 50%;`